# How to split item stacks exactly into fractions using Buildcraft pipes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I'm building an automated factory in tekkit that is fed by items generated through EMC from Energy Collectors. However, i need to split items up into exact amounts so i don't have any overflow problems in some of the later parts of the factory process.

After experimenting with cobblestone and diamond pipes i found out that splitting seems to be probabilistic instead of absolute, which makes sense from a programming standpoint but completely destroys my factory idea since i ended up with one of my testing chests having significantly more items than it should have.

How can i split the incoming items into equal parts or even exact fractions?
I could work with splitting it into halves and then work with a binary system but even that doesn't work precicely enough.

My current idea is to put them into an intermediate chest and have several redstone engines extract them again into different pipes, which should work as long as i keep the redstone engines at equal speed but it still looks overly complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Distribution Transport Pipe](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Distribution_Transport_Pipe) will evenly distribute incoming items to all possible outputs. This will allow you to divide it into fractions of any number divisible by two or (I think) three.

Comment: How did i miss that? Sounds exactly like what i need.

Comment: Good, I hope it works for you! I never really got into Buildcraft pipes, except a tiny bit to extract the output of my EMC Octahedron.

Comment: this is like.. missing from FTB Infinity